# Using REGULAR EXPRESSION to replace string between special characters in oracle

Tags: c++, oracle11g

**select a[b]c[d][e]f[g] from dual;**

I need an output:
**acf**

i.e. Removed with all [] as well as the text between them .

Solution can be in Oracle or C++ function.

Tried erase function in C++ , something like :

```
int main ()
{
 std::string str ("a[b]c[d]e[f]");
 std::cout << str << '\n';

while(1)
{
    std::size_t foundStart = str.find("[");

    //if (foundStart != std::string::npos)
        std::cout << "'[' found at: " << foundStart << '\n';

    str.begin();
    std::size_t foundClose = str.find("]");

    //if (foundClose != std::string::npos)
        std::cout << "']' found at: " << foundClose << '\n';

    str.begin();
    str.erase (foundStart,foundClose); 
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}                        


return 0;
}
```

which returns an output as :

```
a[b]c[d]e[f]
'[' found at: 1
']' found at: 3
ac[d]e[f]
'[' found at: 2
']' found at: 4
ac[f]
'[' found at: 2
']' found at: 4
ac
'[' found at: 18446744073709551615
']' found at: 18446744073709551615
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  basic_string::erase
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough C++ or Oracle to implement it, but the Regular Expression would look something like this, I suppose:

`(?<=[\s\]])[a-z](?=(\[[a-z]\])+[\sa-z])`

This will match **a**, **c** and **f**.

You will need to iterate over the matches and print them accordingly.

The regular expression is decoupled from whatever text is around the target,
**hello there a[b]c[d][e]f[g] way to go!** will have the same matches,
just be sure to **have spaces around the target string a[b]c[d][e]f[g]**

I hope I helped you!

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace(<your_string>,'\[.*?\]')`

Breaking down,

```
\[      --matches single square bracket '['. Should be escaped with a backslash '\', as '[' is regex operator
.*?     --non greedy expression to match minimum text possible
\]      --matches single square bracket ']'. Should be escaped with a backslash '\', as ']' is regex operator
```

Example:

```
SQL> with x(y) as (
        select 'a[b]c[d][][e]f[g][he]ty'
        from dual
)
select y, regexp_replace(y,'\[.*?\]') regex_str
from x;

Y                           REGEX_STR
-----------------------     -----------
a[b]c[d][][e]f[g][he]ty     acfty
```